# Help with JSON deserialized - Creating Account record

Tags: apex, json

need help. Using Class below, I have deserialized JSON response however I`m not able to figure out how should I create an account in Salesforce using this deserialized data. Can someone please help?

```
public class candidateParser{
public cls_rut rut;
public class cls_rut {
    public cls_candidates candidates;
}
public class cls_ candidates {
    public cls_candidate [] candidate;
}
public class cls_candidate {
    public String candidate_id; //3
    public String candidate_code;   //AA12
    public String description;  // Steven S.
}
public static candidateParser parse(String json){
    return (candidateParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, candidateParser.class);
}}
```

**Deserialized JSON:**

> 11:11:02:208 USER_DEBUG [69]|DEBUG|deserializeResults====:
>   candidateParser:[rut=cls_rut:[candidates=cls_candidates:[candidate=(cls_candidate:[candidate_code=AA12,
>   candidate_id=3, description=Steven S.], cls_candidate:[candidate_code=
>   AA13, candidate_id=4, description= Brad Hess],
>   cls_candidate:[candidate_code= AA14, candidate_id=5, description=Brad
>   Jones], cls_candidate:[candidate_code= AA14, candidate_id=6,
>   description=Sample candidate], cls_candidate:[candidate_code= AA16,
>   candidate_id=7, description=ross. k],...)]]]

I`m trying below but I keep getting null response on account name. Please help -

```
candidateParser.cls_candidate deserializeResults2 =     (candidateParser.cls_candidate)JSON.deserialize(replaceJson, candidateParser.cls_candidate.class);    
System.debug('deserializeResults2====: '+deserializeResults2);

Account Acc = New Account ();
Acc.Name =  deserializeResults2.candidate_code;
Insert Acc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deserialize your JSON string with your Apex type as the **candidateParser** class just like what you have done in your first code snippet:

```
    public static candidateParser parse(String json){
    return (candidateParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, candidateParser.class);
}
```

Now that you have deserialized the json, you get more than one candidates and you need to store them in a List of **cls_candidate** . Finally you can create a new Account by fetching values from the List. Here's the entire snippet:

```
    candidateParser deserializeResults2 =  new candidateParser();
    deserializeResults2 = (candidateParser)System.JSON.deserialize(json, candidateParser.class);
    public List<candidateParser.cls_candidate> lstCandidates = new List<candidateParser.cls_candidate>();
    lstCandidates = deserializeResults2.rut.candidates.candidate;

List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
for(candidateParser.cls_candidate cand : lstCandidates){
    Account Acc = New Account ();
    Acc.Name =  cand.candidate_code;
    lstAccount.add(Acc);
}

INSERT lstAccount;
```

Comment: Thank you Aditya, very helpful. Using lstCandidates[0].candidate_code; is just inserting 1 account in Salesforce. How can i loop this to insert multiple records in one time with a list?

Comment: Hi Tom, I have updated the code in my answer